# Await not parsed in esprima 4.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, esprima

Can't get the [esprima](https://github.com/jquery/esprima) 4.0.1 parser to work with 'await'.  Having difficult times to find the relevant options that can be passed into the parse function for 'await', if that is possible.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
const esprima = require('esprima');
esprima.parse("await function_call()")
```

#### Expected output

Describing the code structure containing the await call

#### Actual output

Error: Line 1: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Just checked, Esprima 4.0.1 is perfectly happy to parse `await` in the correct context. (`await function_call()` is a syntax error outside of an `async` function -- not just in Esprima, but per spec.)

Comment: Assumed  that eprima can parse a partial without knowing the async context. Of course it can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a SyntaxError. `await` is only a keyword inside `async function`s:

```
 esprima.parse("(async function() {await function_call()})()")
```

Comment: Of course! The parser can't assume there is an async around it.